# Как в Header добавить Authorization

Tags: c#, httpclient

Возникла следующая проблема, я пытаюсь интегрироваться с сервисом для получения перевода английских слов. Так вот, чтобы я мог им пользоваться мне первым делом необходимо получить Bearer-Token. Чтобы мне его получить мне надо пройти авторизацию. Скрин дока прикрепил ниже.

Написал следующий код:

```
    private readonly string _apiKey = "OGZjODBmM2ItZmM3Mi00YjY4LWE4ODUtZTVlNGQ0NDI5MmFhOjhkN2M3YzIyMzA1NTRhZThiNWJmYmRlODBlYmY1NjZj";
    private readonly string _url = "https://developers.lingvolive.com";
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ExternalApi()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task AuthorizationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{_url}/api/v1.1/authenticate");

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue($"Basic {_apiKey}");

        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

При вызове метода получаю ошибку

```
System.FormatException: "The format of value 'Basic OGZjODBmM2ItZmM3Mi00YjY4LWE4ODUtZTVlNGQ0NDI5MmFhOjhkN2M3YzIyMzA1NTRhZThiNWJmYmRlODBlYmY1NjZj' is invalid."
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: навскидку - кажется, Ваш тоокен короче того, который приведен на картинке. еще - я полез в свой проект, посмотрел - там тоокен имеет длинну 217 символов. Кроме того, кажется, тоокен ндолжен иметь вид "Bearer <куча символов>"

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему)

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",_apiKey);
```

Comment: Круто! И как проосто!

Comment: А зачем вы делаете постоянно "свой" запрос? Смотрите, ваш ключ авторизации наверно стоит задать самому клиенту (`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = ...`), далее можно `new HttpClient()` проинициализировать сразу с `BaseAddress`, нечто на подобии `new() { BaseAddress = new Uri(_url) }` (от `_url` по сути можно отказаться, она вам не нужна). Ну и дальше запросы простым `var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/api/v1.1/authenticate", data);` (заметьте, адрес без указания домена), без постоянного создания `HttpRequestMessage` и другого "мусора".

Comment: `$"{_apiKey}"` можно просто заменить на `_apiKey`. Зачем здесь интерполяция? И да, вам бы освоить настройку `DefaultRrequestHeaders` и `BaseAddress` для `HttpClient`, много лишних телодвижений выполняете при каждом запросе. По сути, весь метод запроса можно к однострочнику свести.